# Gson converter without null

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have two apis , one that send me an Appointment object which its body is like that

```
data class Appointment(
    id:Long = 4,
    name:String = "name"
   ...
)
```

and the other one should receive this body from me

```
{
   name:"name"
}
```

without id field
in kotlin code I want to set the Id to null and Gson should ignore it because it is null
how to do that ?
how to convert kotlin class to json without null values

Comment: Try this way may help you https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-how-to-ignore-fields-with-expose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson skips null values by default. Let's say you have an Appointment class with nullable id:

```kotlin
data class Appointment(
    val id: Long?,
    val name: String,
)
```

If id is null, then it will not appear in json:

```kotlin
val gson = Gson()
gson.toJson(Appointment(null, "hello")) // => {"name":"hello"}
```

If you want to serialize nulls, use `serializeNulls()` method in gson builder:

```kotlin
val gson = GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()
gson.toJson(Appointment(null, "hello")) // => {"id":null,"name":"hello"}
```